# Statsmodels' Negative Binomial: after .fit_regularized(), how to turn PMF into PPF to get the discrete values?

Tags: density-function, negative-binomial-distribution, scipy, statsmodels

I used the package `statsmodels` to fit a Negative Binomial to my data. This data contains ~1500 samples with 21 covariates. Since I have overdispersion in my data because my dependent variable (y) is skewed, I used the `fit_regularized` function (the normal `.fit()` does not make the numerical solver -`newton`, `nm`, `cg`...- converge).

When I plot the fitted data it looks more like a probability mass function (PMF), because I see that the predicted values are not integer (as it is usually the case with NB), but float numbers. I thought I could use `scipy.nbinom.ppf()` to turn these floating numbers into an integer value (as I previously did with Poisson and it's `mu` mean values), but I see that `scipy.nbinom.ppf()` does not receive a `mu`, but a `p`, `q`, and `n` parameters. And I can't make sense of these parameters.

If I use `q=0.95`, `p=0.5`, and `n=predicted values`, I get the following plot:

[image]

And if I use `q=0.5`, `p=0.35`, and `n=predicted values`, I get the following plot:

[image]

It seems that `p` and `q` control the shape of the ppf-converted distribution, but I do not understand the rationale behind it. What is p? What is q?

My question is, what is the proper way of turning the "orange" distribution into an discrete one, so that it resembles the original "grey" distribution as much as possible? It does not feel right to just try values until I force the "orange" to look like the "grey", but I don't know a proper way of turning the PMF (if its a PMF) into the PPF. Does anybody know how to do this, or whether I am in the right track? I only want the discrete values as with Poisson.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NegativeBinomial regression is usually done in a different parameterization from the standard negative binomial distribution.

The predicted value is the mean or expected value of the distribution, usually modeled with a log link. The second parameter is for the dispersion.
The mean of the negative binomial is similar to Poisson a continuous variable.

The parameters have to be converted from the regression parameterization to the usual distribution parameterization which then can be used, for example, with the scipy.stats distribution.

Specific to statsmodels:

The NegativeBinomial has no conversion function built in. A script and link to a stackoverflow question is here https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/106#issuecomment-43961704.

Since version 0.9.0 statsmodels has a generalized version in `NegativeBinomialP` which has an extended `predict` method and a parameter conversion function.
`which` parameter in http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomialP.predict.html
and a currently only internally used
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomialP.convert_params.html

(To fully support these conversion parts is still work in progress in statsmodels)

A notebook to illustrate some of the new countmodel features is here
https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/c932904296270d75366a24ee92a4eb2f

Comment: This was really helpful. Ok, so what I did is 1) using the generalized version of the model, NegativeBinomialP; 2) using the function fit_regularized (due to overdispersion of the skewed Y/endog) to train the model; 3) using the extended .predict() method with "which='mean'" to get the expected value of the distribution; 4) using scipy.stats.binom(q=0.85, n=mean_vals_nb, p=0.15) to get the actual discrete values of the distribution. I am confused with #4: I understood that this conversion is necessary using scipy because is not fully implemented in statsmodels, is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: for 4) look at the source code for predict which='prob' (linked through the doc page) which shows how the parameterization is obtained for the scipy distribution http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.html#NegativeBinomialP.predict

Comment: Most models like NB do not yet have a method like `get_distribution` that would directly return a correctly parameterized scipy.stats distribution instance. So for now, users need to convert some parts by themselves.

Comment: typo in @iamgin 's comment: the distribution name in scipy is `nbinom`

Comment: Aha! Now i connected the dots. It's ok to make the conversion by ourselves (it's actually a good exercise), it's simply that I have difficulties at matching the name of the parameters of pmf()/ppf() in scipy with what statsmodels returns. I checked the code that you linked and I wonder whether it's possible to access from my script to the convert_params function. If I call it like "mymod.convert_params()" it says that the obj does not have this attribute. If I copy the function in my code, it says that mymod.parametrization does not exist. Thanks a lot for your quick and really good responses.

Comment: What's mymod? `parameterization` is the `p` parameter in the NB-P model and corresponds to 1 resp. 2 for the NB1 and NB2 special cases implemented in `NegativeBinomial`.

Comment: I think I did not explain myself properly. Let's say that I do "mymod = sm.NegativeBinomialP(ytr, xtr).fit_regularized(maxiter=5000, disp=1, maxfun=5000, exposure=None, offset=None)". From this "mymod" object, how can I access the internal "convert_params" function, given that if I do "mymod.convert_params()" it does not find it? And regarding this p parameter you mentioned earlier, I did not get this part, can you let me know from this "mymod" object how to retrieve the p parameter? Thanks and much appreciated!

Comment: `fit` methods return an instance of a results class. The underlying method can be accessed through `model` attribute of the results instance. For example `mymod.convert_params(...)`, `p = mymod.parameterization`.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the examples `mymod.model.convert_params(...), p = mymod.model.parameterization`